# How partial_sort is the same as "top N" elements of a list?

Tags: c++, std, partial-sort

Learning about C++, I'm reading the standard algorithms and the [reference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/algorithm) says the following on partial_sort:

```
partial_sort: sorts the first N elements of a range
```

But when I click on the name of the function, this is what is it says for the same function:

```
Rearranges elements such that the range [first, middle) contains the sorted middle − first smallest
elements in the range [first, last).

The order of equal elements is not guaranteed to be preserved. The order of the remaining elements
in the range [middle, last) is unspecified.
```

I don't see how these two are the same! Considering the fact that `partial_sort` takes in an iterator (`middle`) for the item that it will sort up to, I don't think it's the same as "top N". If I want to implement "top N" using this input, it means I have to have an iterator which points to the Nth item of the collection. But if the list is not sorted, how should I know which item is the Nth item?

Comment: `N` is the distance between `first` and `middle`. The iterator you pass to `middle` is not an iterator to any specific value, it acts as the end of the range where the sorted range will be located once the function returns.

Comment: Thanks, now I get it. But then why the function is not asking for the number of items to sort instead!? That would have been more rational if you ask me (I know you don't :) ).

Comment: I suspect the standard library API favors iterators when possible as it avoids some small annoyances related to having to choose between and use `size_type` and `difference_type`. And usually, when using this function, you would have `middle` as an iterator anyway rather than a number as most standard algorithm returns those.

Comment: When Alexander Stephanov thought up the standard library algorithms like these in the 90's, he used Iterators (a design pattern) as the basis for all. So it's legacy. Once you get used to it and see how they chain together you'll start to appreciate the choices.